# Angular Momentum of a Mass that is Tangent to a Tractrix

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

A trailer follows a tractrix path. The trailer hitchpoint trajectory is a straight path.  The trailer has a mass moment of inertia which accumulates angular momentum as it travels from an articulated position towards the asymptote.
I need an expression for hitchpoint travel in terms of ***(t)*** versus angular momentum.
Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Why is this problem interesting for you? What did you tried to solve it? If you don't provide context for your question, other members will find very difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks Daniele.I am writing a paper on fishtailing of caravans where the angular momentum is on the causal list.